# Can I std::move() an element out of a std::vector?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a `std::vector<std::string>` to be re-used in a loop. Is it ok to `std::move` elements out? If I moved the ith element out, then ith *slot* goes into an undefined but valid state, but what about the vector? Is its state still defined and valid? Also, can I `clear()` and then reuse the vector in the next iteration?

EDIT: please read the question before you flag for duplication. I'm asking the state of `v2` after doing `std::move(v2[0])`, not `std::move(v2)`. Also I reuse `v2` after I did `v2.clear()`. How is that similar to the suggested duplication?

EDIT: code example:

```
struct Foo {
    string data;
    /* other data memebers */
    void workOnData();
}

std::vector<std::string> buffer;
Foo foo;
while (1) {
    buffer.clear();
    loadData(buffer); // push data to buffer, at least one element in buffer guaranteed
    foo.data.assign(std::move(buffer[0])); // please don't ask is Foo necessary or why workOnData has to be a member method. THIS IS A SIMPLIFIED EXAMPLE!
    foo.workOnData();
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that removing an element from a vector invalidates the iterator. If you are doing this in a loop you need to handle it slightly different than just erasing the element.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young I think they mean `std::move`. In which case the iterators remain valid.

Comment: state is unspecified, not undefined. See the duplicate…

Comment: @galop1n No it's not. I'm not talking about the state of an object after moving it. But the state of a container after moving its element

Comment: @YZ It is exactly the same by extension.

Comment: @YZ.learner: Why do you think screwing around with an object change the state of the container in any way?

Comment: @galop1n I don't even call `std::move(v2)`! What I did is `std::move(v2[0])`. Also, I do `v2.clear()` before reuse it. By what extension do you think they are the same?

Comment: @MooingDuck Because if the behavior is `undefined`, then it could screw up anything. Isn't it?

Comment: @YZ.learner: are you sure you want std::move?? I guess from your question you just want to keep reusing the same vector and are just concerned that if you remove an element something will go wrong... am I correct?

Comment: @ChrisMaes No, you are not. How could you even come up with that thought?

Comment: could you then provide a code example of what you want to obtain? this is quite unclear...

Comment: If it is for optimization, I guess you could std::swap instead and all objects will still be healthy.

Comment: @YZ.learner: changing the state of an element to any other valid state doesn't affect any container in any way.

Comment: @galop1n: "It is exactly the same by extension." -- No, it is absolutely not the same.

Comment: @MooingDuck You said *screwing around with an object*, and now you are talking about *valid state* !?!?!

Comment: @galop1n Would you mind to remove your incorrect dup flag?

Comment: @StellarVortex But how could I efficiently swap something *into* the vector? That's break the memory of the vector, doesn't it?

Comment: @YZ.learner: WRT: valid state: yes.  No matter how you screw around with an object, if you leave it in valid state, that doesn't affect any container in any way.
WRT swapping: You swap something in, and something (empty state?) out.  He's not referring to appending or actual insertion.

Comment: But, if you are moving the entire vector, then the capacity of the original vector would not be the same.

Comment: This question should absolutely be reopened, it has nothing to do with the linked "duplicate". I just voted to reopen.

Comment: @BorisDalstein Me, too. He's asking about taking elements out of `std::vector`. He's not asking whether the original element (moved FROM) will be valid or usable or known state, but how the `std::vector` will handle having its elements moved out.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley There's only one vote required to reopen this question: maybe you'd like to also vote to reopen? Reminder: you already agreed in comments that it's not a duplicate, and you have the top-voted and accepted answer.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

> Is it ok to std::move elements out?

Yes, it's okay.

> If I moved the ith element out, then ith slot goes into an undefined
>   but valid state

It leaves the element in a valid but *unspecified* state. The difference between those two words is important in C++, but probably not too important to this question. Just thought I should point it out.

> but what about the vector?

The vector is in a valid and well-specified state, though one of its elements is in an unspecified state.

> Also, can I clear() and then reuse the vector in the next iteration?

Yes. Of course. Though you can do a lot more than that. Unlike a moved-from vector, you can still count on the vector having the same size, the same capacity, and all elements other than the one you just moved from remaining unchanged. As well as all references and iterators to elements (including the one you just moved from) remaining valid.